# Using a Generic Trait over S<T> enforces me to have T outlive S

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership-semantics

The boiled-down problem looks as follows:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct WorldState<'a> {
    state: &'a f64,
}

trait CalculateWorldState<T> {
    fn state_value(&mut self, input: &T) -> f64;
}


trait LearningAlgorithm<T> {
    fn print_learning_information(&self, &T);
}

struct EvolutionaryAlgorithm<F, T>
where
    F: CalculateWorldState<T>,
{
    //I need this since I only use T as a method parameter, I do not save it anywhere
    //T are different ways to represent the current worldstate and are
    //short-lived (new ones generated every frame)
    _p_: PhantomData<T>,
    //I don't actually need this one in the real example since I have
    //an instatiated version of type CalculateWorldState saved in the
    //struct but I use phantomdata for simplicity of the example
    _p: PhantomData<F>,
}

impl<F, T> LearningAlgorithm<T> for EvolutionaryAlgorithm<F, T>
where
    F: CalculateWorldState<T>,
{
    fn print_learning_information(&self, input: &T) {
        println!("My learning goes splendid!");
        //do something with &T by calling the object of type
        //CalculateWorldState which we have saved somewhere, but do
        //not save the &T reference anywhere, just look at it
    }
}

struct WorldIsInGoodState {}

impl<'a> CalculateWorldState<WorldState<'a>> for WorldIsInGoodState {
    fn state_value(&mut self, input: &WorldState) -> f64 {
        100.
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Box<LearningAlgorithm<WorldState>> =
        Box::new(EvolutionaryAlgorithm::<WorldIsInGoodState, WorldState> {
            _p: PhantomData,
            _p_: PhantomData,
        });
    {
        let state = WorldState { state: &5. };
        a.print_learning_information(&state);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=353ad2d11bb4cce042362fb6b4279d55&version=stable).

The above code fails to compile:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:59:5
   |
57 |         let state = WorldState { state: &5. };
   |                                          -- temporary value created here
58 |         a.print_learning_information(&state);
59 |     }
   |     ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
60 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
```

`WorldState<'a>` is a very short-lived data type (one per frame), whereas `LearningAlgorithm` is a very long-lived data type (multiple games). But the way I implemented the thing, Rust is eager to believe, that every `WorldState` I pass to `print_learning_information` has to outlive the `LearningAlgorithm`.

What did I do wrong? How could this else be handled?

A few things I would not like to do:

- Have `WorldState` contain a normal state (since in reality it contains a few vectors and not a `f64` and I don't want to copy them around into `WorldState` structs when passing each player its own view of the world)
- Just quit this project and start a new one (you all know it, after you invested some time, you don't want to just throw all the work away)

Comment: The problem appears to be the temporary. Why not define a var in the scope ending at line 60? Something like `let wstate = 5.;` Your real state is more complex so might already be there.

Comment: The problem is, that the inner scope actually is the game loop. I could maybe Magd the state a variable of my game object, so that it survives a whole game and I just change it. But the Learning Algorithm even survives through multiple games and there is no way I can make the game states global variables through all games, since the only objects that live this long are the learningalgorithms, the Game objects are created newly for every game

Comment: Your example works in nightly Rust. I'm not sure yet which changes make it compile.

Comment: Ah, that's [PR 43838](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/43838). It will not help in general case.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be boiled down to

```
struct WorldState<'a> {
    state: &'a f64,
}

trait LearningAlgorithm<T> {
    fn print_learning_information(&self, &T);
}

struct EvolutionaryAlgorithm();

impl<T> LearningAlgorithm<T> for EvolutionaryAlgorithm
{
    fn print_learning_information(&self, input: &T) {
    }
}

fn main() {
    // scope a
    let mut a: Box<LearningAlgorithm<WorldState>> =
        Box::new(EvolutionaryAlgorithm());
    { // scope b
        let val = 5.;
        let state = WorldState { state: &val };
        a.print_learning_information(&state);
    }
}
```

Note that `WorldState` is a type constructor, not a concrete type. Lifetime elision allows you to write `Box<LearningAlgorithm<WorldState>>` with no lifetime parameter explicitly specified for `WorldState`, but it just means that the compiler selects some appropriate lifetime parameter.

In this case lifetime selected for `WorldState` is `scope a`, thus the type of `a` is `Box<LearningAlgorithm<WorldState<'scope_a>>>`. Consequently, `state` should have type `WorldState<'scope_a>`, and the reference it contains should be valid for `scope a`, but a value the reference points to exists only in `scope b`.

You need support for higher-kinded types to make your example work as it is, but Rust doesn't provide it.

The easiest solution is to get rid of `WorldState`'s lifetime parameter by replacing reference with `Rc`. Maybe someone will come up with better solution.